# Declaring member variable outside constructor in es6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-class

I'm still new to es6 and OOP approach, and this question has bumped up in my mind while playing around with React.

As the question title says, I was wondering if it is a good practice to assign values to member variable that has not been declared in constructor.

So, for example:

```
class MyClass {
    constructor(props) {
        this._props = props;
    }

    render() {
        // declared in constructor
        console.log(this._props);

        // new member variable
        this._anotherProp = 'New value';
        console.log(this._anotherProp);

    }
}
```

So in this case, is it alright to declare this._anotherProp in render method, or is it a bad practice to do it? And what would be the recommended way of assigning member variables outside constructor, if there is any?

I have seen similar approach in React when defining Refs (https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) although I'm not sure if it represents the same use cases as my example.

Comment: Dump OOP for Functional programming ;)

Comment: I don't think it's bad practice, but it does beg the question, _why is it not in the constructor?_

Comment: @evolutionxbox In some cases I had to assign a new value from member methods rather than from the constructor, and constructor doesn't let me declare member variable without actual value assigned.

Comment: @Da-WoonChung The question was: *why is there no initial value* that could be assigned in the constructor? `null` or `undefined` would be fine, as long as your instance is valid.

Comment: You could assign `null`?

Comment: Yes, it's a bad practice, changing the shape of an instance afterwards is detrimental to performance and maintainability.

Comment: @Bergi I see, I've never thought about that, indeed :'D This could be another dumb question but is there any 'benefit' of doing that or is it more for code clarity?

Comment: @Bergi do you have any perf data for that?

Comment: @Bergi Cool, thanks a lot!

Comment: @evolutionxbox So would you also still recommend assigning null beforehand in constructor? And I was also wondering what's the case with React when defining Refs...

Comment: I would mainly for readability, but I don't know the more detailed performance aspects.

Comment: @evolutionxbox I see, thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Self-answering to this after 5 years

Definitely try to assign an initial value that is closest to your desired variable type for readability, just as you would define a type in TypeScript.